# About downsampling in Unet segmentation architecture

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

Downsampling helps to reduce the shape but why downsampling is needed in Unet segmentation architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Most of modern convolution neural network architectures use max-pooling to downsample (such as U-Net), not depending only on the stride to achieve this because pooling introduces a small location invariance to the network architecture and is faster to compute.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288261/why-is-max-pooling-necessary-in-convolutional-neural-networks) might provide you more information.